# Speed improval through conditional function execution?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance

I have a website with multiple pages, each of them with custom event handlers attached to certain elements. Each page has an id in the html markup (#page1, #page2, ...).

In my javascript file for the website I have seperated the functions for each site in self executing modules, simplified like so:

```
//module 1 for stuff that happens on #page1
(function() {
    // stuff to happen, events, delegations, preparations, etc
})();
```

I thought I could execute certain page related modules only if the #id is found in the current document like:

```
if( $("#page1").length ) {
   // call module 1
};
```

... because a lot of event delegation happens in some modules.

Is this a common/good approach to speed up things? Or is it better to include the modules in seperated js files only on the subsites where they are needed? Or any other method/ideas?

Comment: If the speed matters , then why are you using jquery for operation which gains nothing from it ? Are you aware that you just created a huge object , just to check if `document.getElementById('page1') !== null` ?!

Comment: `$('#page1')` automatically shortcuts to `getElementById` - I know it's cool to advise against jQuery, but he's asking about the performance/memory implications of a significant amount of code. If I had to guess what _wasn't_ the bottleneck in his app, I'd bet it was these selectors.

Comment: @Alex - tereško's comment was in regard to using `$()` rather than the DOM method. It's like using `$(this).val()` when `this.value` has exactly the same result, only very much faster (as shown [here](http://jsperf.com/thisvsjquerythis)). It all adds up, not everyone is running the latest and greatest PC and browser.

Comment: @tereško - thx for the advice. I try to use native js code as much as possible, like this.value or this.id. but you are right, when only checking if an element with an id exists I shouldn´t call jquery on that element, because of the "huge object" that will also be created by doing so.

Comment: I am aware of the performance implications of using jQuery in that case. I am also aware that if you run a jsperf, you can do a few million more operations per second with the raw dom version. He already is loading jQuery, so there is no extra cost there. My point is that when talking about trying to improve the performance of someone's page, nitpicking on something that _really doesn't add up_ is not helpful. Let him use jQuery. It _will not_ affect his page speed in this case. If it was in a loop, perhaps, but he should focus on his bottlenecks and ignore sidetracks like this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put all the code in a single js file so it is cached. Put an id on the body or similar element, then put each module of code in a separate function. Then have an object to hold module references linked to body element ids, then in the onload:

```
var modules = {
   id1: function() { /* stuff for page 1 */},
   id2: function() { /* stuff for page 2 */},
   ...
}
var id = document.body.id
if (id && id in modules) {
  modules[id]();
}
```

Then you just give the body the id of the function that should run for that page.

Comment: nice nice ;), i have seen that pattern before, it think i´ll use it.